# how to get purchased product from inapp purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, restore

**My Requirement:**
I am creating an app in which user can play a quiz and it is paid. There is no login functionality in my application and in-app purchase functionality is integrated to play a quiz.

**My problem is as follow:**
If a user purchase some coin from one device and then install app in another device with same apple id then how can I get purchased product detail in second device?

Is there a way to get purchase history from in-app Purchase and restore user purchase?

Comment: Have you read the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267) and the [StoreKit reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit)?

Comment: What type of in-app-purchase you are using?

Comment: @user816 non-consumable inapp purchase

Comment: If it is a non-consumable IAP then you can simply provide a "restore" button to allow them to restore their purchases. It is described in the guide that rmaddy linked to. However, you mentioned "coin"; that is typically a consumable purchase type, not a non-consumable. Are they purchasing access to individual quizzes or are they purchasing coins that they can use to play a game?

Comment: @Paulw11 I can add Restore button instead of Buy but how can i detect that it is already purchased from other device?i don't have any support from server side.

Comment: If they have logged in with the same Apple ID then the restore process will tell you what they have purchased.